# Spring cloud configuration: Exception on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Got a problem with spring-cloud-starter-config version 4.0.3.

`eureka-server.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:4.0.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config:4.0.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:4.0.3'
}
```

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server

  profiles:
    active: dev

  config:
    import: configserver:http://localhost:8071
```

Application failed on startup with exception below. Found, that I can add `optional:` to prevent failure, but then application doesn't import it's configuration.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'configserver:http://localhost:8071'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:143) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:128) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:121) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$resolve$1(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:102) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:113) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:102) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:94) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:98) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:115) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:242) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:229) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:96) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:109) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:94) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:174) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:133) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at pw.qubique.core.microservice.eureka.EurekaServerApplication.main(EurekaServerApplication.java:12) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/' or File.separator
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferencesForFile(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:234) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:140) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

When sending `GET` request on `http://localhost:8071/eureka-server/dev`, it works.

Comment: can you update your question with your dependencies. It looks like you might be missing `spring-cloud-starter-config`

Comment: @spencergibb yep, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this question. Just mixed up `spring-cloud-config` and `spring-cloud-starter-config`.

Comment: Also, we recommend that you use dependency management for Spring Cloud deps rather than passing the version of each of them separately.